# R: multiply columns by rows to create country-specific index

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to create a country-specific index based on the import share of certain food commodities.

I have the following data: *Prices* contains time-series data on commodity prices for a number of food commodities. *Weights* contains data on the country-specific import shares for the relevant commodities (see mock data).

What I want to do is to create a country-specific food-price index which is the sum of the price-series of imported commodities multiplied by the import share.

So in the example data the food-price index for Australia will be:

```
FOODct = 0.12 * WHEATt + 0.08 * SUGARt
```

Where *c* indicates country and *t* time.

So basically my question is: How do I multiply the columns by the rows for each country?

I have some experience with R but trying to solve this I seem to be punching above my weight. I also haven't found any useful pointers elsewhere so I was hoping that maybe anyone of you might have good suggestions.

```
## Code to create mock data:

## Generate data on country weights
country<-c(rep("Australia",2),rep("Zimbabwe",3))
item<-c("Wheat","Sugar","Wheat","Sugar","Soybeans")
itemcode<-c(1,2,1,2,3)
share<-c(0.12,0.08,0.16,0.08,0.03)
weights<-data.frame(country,item,itemcode,share)

## Generate data on price index
date<-seq(as.Date("2005/1/1"),by="month",length.out=12)
Wheat<-runif(12,80,160)
Sugar<-runif(12,110,230)
Soybeans<-runif(12,60,130)
prices<-data.frame(date,Wheat,Sugar,Soybeans)
```

**EDIT: Solution**

Thanks to alexwhan for his suggestion ( I can't upvote unfortunately due to lack of stackoverflow street cred). And dnlbrky for the solution which was easiest to implement with the original data.

```
## Load data.table package
require(data.table)

## Convert data to data table
prices<-data.table(prices)
weights<-data.table(weights,key="item")

## Extract names for all the food commodities
vars<-names(prices)[!names(prices) %in% "date"] 

## Unstack items to create table in long format
prices<-data.table(date=prices[,date], stack(prices,vars),key="ind")

## Rename the columns
setnames(prices,c("values","ind"),c("price","item"))

## Calculate the food price index
priceindex<-weights[prices,allow.cartesian=T][,list(index=sum(share*price)),
                              by=list(country,date)]

## Order food price index if not done automatically
priceindex<-priceindex[order(priceindex$country,priceindex$date),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would unstack/reshape the items in the weights table, and then use `data.table` to join the prices and the weights.

```
## Generate data table for country weights:
weights<-data.table(country=c(rep("Australia",2),rep("Zimbabwe",3)),
                    item=c("Wheat","Sugar","Wheat","Sugar","Soybeans"),
                    itemcode=c(1,2,1,2,3),
                    share=c(0.12,0.08,0.16,0.08,0.03),
                    key="item")

## Generate data table for price index:
prices<-data.table(date=seq(as.Date("2005/1/1"),by="month",length.out=12),
                   Wheat=runif(12,80,160),
                   Sugar=runif(12,110,230),
                   Soybeans=runif(12,60,130))

## Get column names of all the food types:
vars<-names(prices)[!names(prices) %in% "date"]    

## Unstack the items and create a "long" table:
prices<-data.table(date=prices[,date], stack(prices,vars),key="ind")

## Rename the columns:
setnames(prices,c("values","ind"),c("price","item"))

prices[1:5]
##          date     price     item
## 1: 2005-01-01  88.25818 Soybeans
## 2: 2005-02-01  71.61261 Soybeans
## 3: 2005-03-01  77.91082 Soybeans
## 4: 2005-04-01 129.05806 Soybeans
## 5: 2005-05-01  74.63005 Soybeans

## Join the weights and prices tables, multiply the share by the price, and sum by country and date:
weights[prices,allow.cartesian=T][,list(index=sum(share*price)),by=list(country,date)]

##       country       date    index
##  1:  Zimbabwe 2005-01-01 27.05711
##  2:  Zimbabwe 2005-02-01 34.72842
##  3:  Zimbabwe 2005-03-01 35.23615
##  4:  Zimbabwe 2005-04-01 39.05027
##  5:  Zimbabwe 2005-05-01 39.48388
##  6:  Zimbabwe 2005-06-01 33.43677
##  7:  Zimbabwe 2005-07-01 32.55172
##  8:  Zimbabwe 2005-08-01 34.86790
##  9:  Zimbabwe 2005-09-01 33.29748
## 10:  Zimbabwe 2005-10-01 38.31180
## 11:  Zimbabwe 2005-11-01 31.29709
## 12:  Zimbabwe 2005-12-01 40.70930
## 13: Australia 2005-01-01 21.07165
## 14: Australia 2005-02-01 27.47660
## 15: Australia 2005-03-01 27.03025
## 16: Australia 2005-04-01 29.34917
## 17: Australia 2005-05-01 31.95188
## 18: Australia 2005-06-01 26.22890
## 19: Australia 2005-07-01 24.58945
## 20: Australia 2005-08-01 27.44728
## 21: Australia 2005-09-01 27.02199
## 22: Australia 2005-10-01 31.58282
## 23: Australia 2005-11-01 24.42326
## 24: Australia 2005-12-01 31.70109
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option. There will absolutely be a neater way to do this, but it should get you going.

First, I'm going to get `weights` into wide format so that it's easier to work with for our purposes:

```
library(reshape2)
weights.c <- dcast(weights, country~item)
#     country Soybeans Sugar Wheat
# 1 Australia       NA  0.08  0.12
# 2  Zimbabwe     0.03  0.08  0.16
```

Then I've used `apply` to go through each row of `weights.c` and calculate the 'food-price index' (tell me if this is being calculated incorrectly, I think I followed the example right...).

```
FOOD <- as.data.frame(apply(weights.c, 1, function(x) 
  as.numeric(x[3]) * prices$Soybeans + 
  as.numeric(x[3])*prices$Sugar + as.numeric(x[4])*prices$Wheat))
```

Adding in the country and date identifiers:

```
colnames(FOOD) <- weights.c$country
FOOD$date <- prices$date
FOOD
#    Australia Zimbabwe       date
# 1   35.04337 39.99131 2005-01-01
# 2   38.95579 44.72377 2005-02-01
# 3   33.45708 38.50418 2005-03-01
# 4   30.42181 34.04647 2005-04-01
# 5   36.03443 39.90905 2005-05-01
# 6   46.21269 52.29347 2005-06-01
# 7   41.88694 48.15334 2005-07-01
# 8   34.47848 39.83654 2005-08-01
# 9   36.32498 40.60091 2005-09-01
# 10  33.74768 37.17185 2005-10-01
# 11  38.84855 44.87495 2005-11-01
# 12  36.45119 40.11678 2005-12-01
```

Hopefully this is close enough to what you're after...

Comment: I can replicate your results although I changed  _as.numeric(x[3]) * prices$Soybeans_ to  _as.numeric(x[2]) * prices$Soybeans_ as I thought it was a typo. I have problems using the solution in my original data as I get an error when I reshape the data (_Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length_) and dataframe weights.c returns all the commodities as an integer instead of the numerical values. Any idea what could be the cause?